# Execution output of program

Tags: c

Why does the below given program prints -128

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char i = 0;
    for (; i >= 0; i++)
        ;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Also can I assign int value to char without type-casting it. And if I used a print statement in for loop it prints till 127 which is correct but this program current prints -128. Why

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the `for`. Do you intend it?

Comment: Yes. The question is correct and the same way as I want it

Comment: Why is there a downvote on this question? It poses a good question about `signed char` vs `unsigned char` and how the signedness of a char is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 5):

If `char` is a `signed` type on your platform then the behaviour of the program is **undefined**: overflowing a `signed` type is undefined behaviour in C.

A 2's complement 8 bit number with a value of -128 has the same bit pattern as a unsigned 8 bit number with value +128. It seems that this is what is happening in your case. And -128 is, of course, a termination condition for your loop. (You could even call it "wraparound to the smallest negative"). But **don't** rely on this.

Comment: And if it isn't signed, then the program will lock in an eternal loop.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed, that brings back bad memories of a nasty bug I once had. The celebrations at 3am on spotting it made up for the pain. Since then I use `>` rather than `>=` whenever possible.

Comment: But when I used unsigned char i=0, program went into infinite loop

Comment: @OmkarPatil Indeed. So no matter what you do, you can't turn this program into something meaningful.

Comment: @OmkarPatil: of course it would, it would be incremented modulo 256. That behaviour is defined, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

According to N1570, whether a `char` is signed is implementation-defined:(Emphasis mine)

> 6.2.5 Types
>
> 15 The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types. **The implementation shall
>   define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as
>   either signed char or unsigned char.**

If it's unsigned, it will never overflow:

> 9 The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a
>   subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the
>   representation of the same value in each type is the same. **A
>   computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow**, because a
>   result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer
>   type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
>   value that can be represented by the resulting type.

For example, suppose `UCHAR_MAX == 127`(usually it'll be 255, though), `127 + 1 = (127 + 1) % (UCHAR_MAX + 1) = (127 + 1) % (127 + 1) = 0`.

But if it's signed, the behavior is undefined, which means anything can happen. CHAR_MAX + 1 can be equal to CHAR_MIN, 0, or whatever. What's more, "undefined behavior" indicates that the program is possible to crash, although it's not very likely in practice.

In your case, it seems that `char` is signed, and `CHAR_MAX + 1 == CHAR_MIN`. Why? Just because your implementation defined so, and your are lucky enough to miss a crash this time. But this is not portable and reliable at all.

Comment: Presumably you mean CHAR_MAX + 1 == -CHAR_MIN. By the way the only other possibility allowed is a 1's complement signed which will give you CHAR_MAX == -CHAR_MIN.

Comment: I think in this OP's case, `CHAR_MAX == 127`, `CHAR_MIN == -128`

Comment: I agree. Although the macro would define CHAR_MIN as -127 -1.

Comment: @Bathsheba I didn't know that before, but what about signed magnitude numbers?